# Set a value to an object array

Tags: java, class, object, methods

```
public class Jeux {

 public static void main(String [] args) {

    int nPlayer= 0;
    String name;
    boolean ok = false;
    Player[] groupe = null;

    do {
        try {
            System.out.print("How many player: ");              
            nPlayer= Clavier.lireInt();
            ok = true;
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {              
            System.out.println("ERROR, enter a number");
        }
    } while(!ok);

    groupe = new Player[nPlayer];
    System.out.println(groupe.length);

    for(int i=0; i<groupe.length; i++){
        try{
            System.out.print("Enter the name of the player " + (i + 1));
            name = Clavier.lireString();
            groupe[i].setNom(name);

        } catch(NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
 }
}
```

why can't I set the name for `groupe[i]` --> `groupe[i].setNom(nom);`. I get an exception.

I try to create multiple object without knowing the length of the array.

Maybe there's other possibility with array list and other method but im in school and we didn't see other method for the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to instantiate each `Player` object *in addition* to instantiating the array which holds them:

```
name = Clavier.lireString();
groupe[i] = new Player();     // replace this with actual constructor
groupe[i].setNom(name);
```

Your code is catching a `NullPointerException` which is precisely what I would expect from your current code.